# Is it possible to implement 3D mapviews with iOS 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6, mapkit, ios6-maps

I would like to implement the great "Google Earth" look of the new iOS6 map app in 3D mode.  I've looked thru the latest version of the MapKit framework, as well as Apple's doc set, and I can't find any mention of how to implement it.  Does this mean that that feature is private API, and not available to developers at this time?

Comment: I think it's still a private API.

Check my answer on [this SO post][1].


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12563254/how-to-develop-3d-maps-in-an-iphone-application/12686739#12686739

Answer (score 0):

This is definitely not a public API. Probably it's not even a private API but just implemented in Maps.app.